# How to deduce that a discrete random variable $X$ is bimodal?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

The following question is on negative binomial distribution. Does anyone have any clues on how to solve part (b)(ii) (see below the pink stripes in the picture)? Any explanation or tips are welcome.

[image]

Comment: Never post unsearchable images containing text.  Instead, typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: Use $b(i)$ and the definition of bimodal.

Comment: @YJT Hello. Thank you for your advice. I sort of understood it now. What I did was the following: suppose the modes are X=x and X=x+1, then make P(X=x) equal to P(X=x+1). Divide both sides by the RHS and use part (a) to simplify the division which will now equal to 1. Then solve for x and you get x=(r-1)/p. Now, since X is the number of the trial upon which the rth success falls, it can only be a positive integer. Hence (r-1)/p must be a positive integer. However, what I don’t understand is why the difference between the modes should be a one. Couldn’t the modes be eg X=3 and X=10?

Comment: According to the first part, $P(X=x)$ is an increasing function until $x_0=\tfrac{r-1}{p}$ and decreasing afterwards. You cannot have two maxima far apart.

Comment: @YJT Very helpful, thank you. Is it always the case with this type of distribution that when there are two or more modes, they’ll differ by one integer?

Comment: What do you mean by "this type"?

Comment: @YJT I mean negative binomial distributions. Is it always the case with negative binomial distributions that when there are two or more modes, they’ll differ by one integer?

Comment: That's exactly what is proven in this exercise. NB is either single peaked or bimodal.

Comment: @YJT Right, but suppose it's given that a NB is bimodal and that one of the modes is x=5, is it then correct to say that the second mode must occur at x=4 or x=6?